# Win8.1 doesn't see Android device?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, windows, usb-connection-mode, usb-drivers

Not sure why, but even though my Android is connected, charging, and set to Media Device mode, Win8 will not even notice it. Any advice? Ask any questions necessary.

It's an Moto X 2nd gen KitKat and I'm trying to connect it to a Win8.1 laptop. It doesn't have a slot for SD cards, and for some reason my cell provider isn't letting me update to Lolli.

Update: Just installed Motorola Device Manager, and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your computer does not have the drivers needed to communicate with the phone. **It is like speaking german to an american, you do not understand what they are saying.**

First of all, You can search for your phone's drivers via google search. Trust me, i know what the problem is, this also happened to my Nexus 4.

It all should be good from their. If there are still problems, just PM me. Or you can tell me the device name. (ex. Samsung Galaxy Note 2, Nexus 5, OnePlus One, etc.) or if it is a generic phone. tell me.

EDIT: Search ADB Drivers on google. It is a universal driver, and its the one I used with my phone. If this doesn't work, then I don't know what.

MORE GOODNESS:

Also, I forgot to point out. You have to enable USB DEBUGGING on your phone. If you already have developer options enabled in settings, it should be there. **IF YOU DONT HAVE DEVELOPER OPTIONS UNLOCKED**, go to settings > About Phone.  And tap on the build number 5 times.

**IF YOU NOW HAVE DEV. OPTIONS**, go to settings > developer options. And click on "Enable USB debugging"

Hope this works.

Comment: You can PM someone? #noob Anyway, I think I found the driver site, just didn't think I'd need one, I thought it came pre-equipped like with a flash drive. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: ... Wait, that didn't work. I just got Motorola Device Manager (Phone is a Moto X) and nothing changed.

Comment: Then you should google ADB on google. It is s universal driver and it worked for my phone when mine didn't want to connect.